# React JS - How can I show 2 dropdowns and show data from static json

Tags: json, reactjs, static, dropdown

I am new for React JS
I am having 2 dropdowns : Country and City.
I want to show city based on country with the help of static json
Can anybody help me with the way?

```
 [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "country": "India",
    "cities": [
      {
        "id": "01",
        "cityName": "Delhi"
      },
      {
        "id": "02",
        "cityName": "Mumbai"
      },
      {
        "id": "03",
        "cityName": "Pune"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "country": "Canada",
    "cities": [
      {
        "id": "01",
        "cityName": "Toronto"
      },
      {
        "id": "02",
        "cityName": "Ottawa"
      },
      {
        "id": "03",
        "cityName": "Winnipeg"
      }
    ]
  }
]

import * as React from 'react'; import * as styles from './App.module.scss'; const App = () => { return ( <div className={styles.app}> <div> <span>Country: </span> <select> <option>Select Country</option> </select> </div> <div> <span>City: </span> <select> <option>Select Country</option> </select> </div> </div> ); }; export default App;
```

Comment: import * as React from 'react';
import * as styles from './App.module.scss';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.app}>
           <div>
                <span>Country: </span>
                <select>
                    <option>Select Country</option>            
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>City: </span>
                <select>
                    <option>Select Country</option>            
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;

Comment: I dont have time to write the complete code but this is what you should do. First convert json string to JObject then process that object to create `Touple` with key value (country as key) and then (city list as value) and then set them in state. Then bind that state value to component and on change of country selection fire handler which will update the state.

Answer (score 1):

just set a method to `onchange` for `dropdown` country and in that method filter the city by selected country

```
const data = "your JSon"
@computed get countries(){
.map(item => {
return <option key ={item.country.id}> {item.country.name} </option>
}
}
let cities : [];

@computed get cities(){
if(this.cities == null || this.cities == undefined)
return null;

this.cities.map(item => {
return <option key ={item.id}> {item.name} </option>
}
}

countryChange(){
this.cities = data.filter(item => {return item.country === "your value"})[0].cities
}

<select onchange= {this.countryChange}> {this.countries} </select>
<select onchange= > {this.cities } </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this out and pass data in as props. You should refactor as necessary and make more generic.

```
class SelectComponent extends Component {

  state = {country: 0, cityName: 0};

  clicked = () => { console.log("clicked") };

  handleChange = (key, ev) => {
    let newState = { [key]: parseInt(ev.target.value) };

    //reset city to 0 if country changes
    if(key !== "cityName") {
        newState.cityName = 0;
    }

    this.setState(newState);
  };

  render() {

    const { data } = this.props;

    const select = (title, data, fieldName) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <span>{title}:</span>
                <select onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(fieldName, event)}>
                    {data.map((value, key) =>
                      <option value={key}
                              selected={this.state[fieldName] === key}
                      >
                        {value[fieldName]}
                      </option>)
                    }
                </select>
            </div>);
  };

    return (
        <div className={styles.app}>
            {
                [select("Country", data, "country"), select("City", data[this.state.country].cities, "cityName")]
            }
        </div>
    );
  }
};
```

[Live Preview](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ihfcac?embed=1&file=MyComponent.jsx)

Comment: [ts] Property 'cityName' does not exist on type '{ [x: number]: number; }'.
any - Getting this error